Track my slight changes to an external git repository I cannot push
I would like to use the code stored in an external git repository (I mean I am not a contributor for this code, I cannot push or create branches) but of course I need to change some files before compile it (for example for path, options, etc).
My question is: could you propose me a workflow to keep track of (only) my own slight changes in git.
duplicate the repo: first, it's not very nice for the developers, then difficult to follow evolutions of the origin repository
fork: there is no reason to do a fork as my changes are minor and do not constitute any real contribution to the project (who cares about the paths on my disk, and the options I used at a time).
To illustrate my question, for example imagine I git clone recipes to build a linux kernel. I want to keep track of the different options and modules I included... And if the origin linux kernel evolves I would like to be able to integrate the changes, even if it means have my own settings evolved accordingly (i.e. merge in a way).
By the way, I work on linux, so probably there is also a solution with symbolic links and submodules?
Any good idea?
Cheers

I would use a branch for this:

Clone the external repository locally.

Create a branch based off whichever remote branch is appropriate (I’ll assume that’s origin/main).

Make your changes and commit them to your branch.

Whenever you want to update your branch with changes made to the external repository:
git fetch
git rebase origin/main

If there are any conflicts you’ll have to resolve them.


If you want to back your changes up somewhere, you might as well fork the original repository, there’s no meaning associated with that and it’s fine to fork repositories when you don’t intend to contribute back.
